# Can I use map of an arrays item as props for other components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I'm new to programing and I don't know what's the best approach here. I made a StudentCard and I have the mapping in this component like this:

```
<ul className="-my-5 divide-y divide-slate-200">
      {props.binderMemberships.map((binderMembership) => (
    <li key={binderMembership.id} className="py-4">
       <div className="flex items-center space-x-4">
             <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                 <Avatar of={binderMembership.binder.student} size="8" />
             </div>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I want the Avatar be separate from this, so I made another child component such as:

```
import Avatar from "./Avatar"
import type { Binder, BinderMember, User } from "@prisma/client"
export interface AvatarLoaderProps {
    binderMemberships: (BinderMember & { binder: Binder & { student: User } })[]
    user: User
}
export function AvatarLoader(props: AvatarLoaderProps) {
    return (
      <div className="flex-shrink-0">
          <Avatar of={props.binderMemberships.binder.student} size="8" />
      </div>
    )
}
```

Here is my issue: I need to pass the binderMembership that is given to me by mapping in the parent component but I need it in the child component. how can I pass it as a props since it's just an item of items and is just a name?

Comment: can you show what this `map of an arrays item` is?

Comment: sure why wouldn't you be able to? just handle the props properly. But usually when passing a map of components into another component, you're passing them as children, which will always be available via `props.children`

Comment: @mstephen19 How should I handle that? in this situation, I need bindermembership not bindermemberships that is the main array. I need to pass the item of items.

Comment: @Bravo it's an array of objects like {id: 49, binderId: 12, userId: 2, creatorId: 9, createdAt: '2022-04-06T19:38:38.0} which each has another object inside. I need to pass one item of these items as a props

Comment: so, you've just described an array of objects - however, I asked what **you** mean by `map of an arrays item` - nevermind, I see you meant items not item

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you forgot to close the tags of mapping. After `</li>` it should have `)}`.

Second, you can pass props to nested components or put it higher, which is simple to do. You want to pass to nested, so it must declare this in your component. I don't know if you have a class/functional component, a classic function or an arrow. But it should look like this:

`function NameOfFunction ({ol}) { }`

I dispatched props because it is easier to use it.

Third is to use the value somewhere you want using handlebars `{}` i.e. `{props.id}`.

And that's all.